# Sending a Yahoo Email with JavaMail API

Tags: jakarta-mail, java

I am trying to send an email to a yahoo email account with this code. 
However, I get this message:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: winmo.smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465, response: -1

I dont know what is wrong. I am new to java.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);         
        String to = "myemail@yahoo.com";
        System.out.println("Type the subject of the email");
        String subject = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Type the content of the message");
        String body = s.nextLine();

        String from = "web@gmail.com";
        String host = "winmo.smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("sent");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check for smtp server configuration those appeared to be wrong in your code .

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: Please see this list of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), this [Yahoo mail example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#yahoomail), and these [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  Also, if your From address is Gmail, you almost certainly want to connect to Gmail to send the message, independent of what the To address is.